# GA Ecommerce tracking data not being sent

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following ecommerce tracking code. I am making use of multiple trackers. The pageviews are getting tracked correctly but when I view the ecommerce reports no data is coming through. What am I missing?

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-34658431-1', 'auto', {'name' : 'primary'}); // primary tracker
ga('create', 'UA-64375824-1', 'auto', {'name': 'secondary'});  // secondary tracker.

ga('secondary.send', 'pageview');
ga('primary.send', 'pageview');

ga('primary.require', 'ecommerce');
ga('secondary.require', 'ecommerce');
//ga('primary.ecommerce:clear');
//ga('secondary.ecommerce:clear');

var transaction_id = '1';

var ga_transaction = {
    'id': transaction_id,
    'affiliation': 'primary',
    'revenue': '2.46',
    'shipping': '',
    'tax': ''
};

ga('primary.ecommerce:addTransaction', ga_transaction);
ga('secondary.ecommerce:addTransaction', ga_transaction);

var ga_item = {
    'id': transaction_id,
    'name': 'Test',
    'sku': 'Pc6Q',
    'category': 'eBook',
    'price': '2.00',
    'quantity': '1'
};

ga('primary.ecommerce:addItem', ga_item);
ga('secondary.ecommerce:addItem', ga_item);

ga('secondary.ecommerce:send');
ga('primary.ecommerce:send');
```

Comment: I run this in the javascript console of my browser and it run flawless. To exclude the obvious, since it takes a while before ecommerce data is processed (up to 24 hours), did you wait for some time for the data to appear in the reports ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff You're right, I didn't wait long enough! What's the point of Google Analytics refresh report link then? It even has a timestamp! Would you mind adding an answer to "just wait" and not to rely on the refresh report link. Maybe link to this: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like pointed out in my comment (and like you have now found in the documentation) there is a processing latency (and typically it's much longer for transactions and custom dimensions and custom metrics than for pageviews and events).

For the benefit of others here is the relevant part [from the documenation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en):

> Data processing latency Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard
>   accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Google
>   Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day.
>   This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To
>   restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions you send
>   to < 200,000 per day. For Premium accounts, this limit is extended to
>   2 billion hits per month.

Data *might* be processed quicker but you cannot rely on it.

So this problem can be resolved simply by waiting.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear for anyone that might not see data in their GA account.